# cannot be resolved to a variable in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, compiler-errors

I have recently checked out a project from CVS. I get an error :

> nl cannot be resolved to a variable.

other staffs don't face this error in their project. I think it is related to configuration.

```
    String captchaTextInServer = (String)request.getSession()
                .getAttribute(
                    nl.captcha.servlet.Constants.SIMPLE_CAPCHA_SESSION_KEY);
```

My Eclipse:Marse 2.0
Jdk 1.6
tomcat:6.0.37

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

that error was because of one of jar files . 
one Class jar file should have be added into classpath.